# How should I handle site feedback messages (success/errors) to the user in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, web, message, feedback

Such as "Username not found", "Problems logging you off", "Logout successful", and so on. Any feedback the website needs to give the user.

I made a class Feedback_Messages, declaring in instance of itself upon running (called in the page header). All messages are stored in a 3D array, according to message type (i.e. error, positive,...). A Get Message function prints out all of the waiting messages (I can make it look fancy when it's done).

Sometimes it works. Before I get into debugging, is this even a good way of doing this, or is there a best practice or available project to manage messages from different class objects to the user? Maybe in session? I'm new to php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 'flash' system to store the message in session, and display it on the next page viewed before removing the flash.